# Category items not matching the search done

Tags: magento-1.8, category, filter, search, catalogsearch

First of all, I have been trying to get a better search engine for Magento without adding a plugin.

After changing some query options I have got more or less the result for a search I was looking for. And now I have seen there is a little bug on the category side. At the left side of the products shown. If the product I have searched get 5 products, 2 for textile and 3 for technology, for example, I see on the category menu:

> Textile(2)
>   Technology(3)

So this is right, the results are correct, the problem is when I click on it, it is  supposed I should get the 2 textile products when click on it, but this is not happening, it shows me the whole textile products from my database.

When not doing a search on the website and I do only navigate on my products it works perfect. There is something interesting and it is that after doing a search the link changes to: `/catalogsearch/result/?q=whateverilookedfor` and after clicking on textile I get: `/textile.html?q=whateverilookedfor` so the search is saved but not showing up.

Do anyone know if there is an option to activate the filter search when click there or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to solve it so I post it just in case someone needs it in the future.
 I'm not quite sure if this happened because I changed something on my code someday or it's because of Magento's default features.
What I saw is that when clicking on the category link it redirected to the whole items from that category so I changed the href when having done a search. The file I've modified is:

> /app/design/frontend/default/yourtheme/template/catalog/layer/filter.phtml

And I removed the whole code:

```
    <ol>
    <?php foreach ($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
        <li>
            <?php if ($_item->getCount() > 0): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->urlEscape($_item->getUrl()) ?>"><?php echo $_item->getLabel() ?></a>
            <?php else: echo $_item->getLabel() ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            (<?php echo $_item->getCount() ?>)
        </li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    </ol>
```

for this one.

```
    <ol>
    <?php foreach ($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
        <li>
            <?php if (($_item->getCount() > 0) && (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'catalogsearch') === false)): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->urlEscape($_item->getUrl()) ?>"><?php echo $_item->getLabel() ?></a>
            <?php 

            elseif(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'catalogsearch') == true): //afegitó 
                $category = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')->addFieldToFilter('name', $_item->getLabel());
                $cat_det=$category->getData();
                $category_id=$cat_det[0][entity_id];

            ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?>&cat=<?php echo $category_id ?>"><?php echo $_item->getLabel() //afegitó ?></a>
            <?php else: echo $_item->getLabel() ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            (<?php echo $_item->getCount() ?>)
        </li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
    </ol>
```